# How do async void methods report progress in ASP.NET Core applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

In .NET Framework, `async void` methods notified their synchronization context when they started or finished and any exception thrown out of an `async void` method was directly raised to the [synchronization context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). In ASP.NET Core, this synchronization context [was removed](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html).

So where does an `async void` method report that it started, finished, and if any exceptions occured in an ASP.NET Core application since the synchronization context no longer exists?

Comment: There is no word "progress" on the linked page.

Comment: `async void` methods *do not* report their progress - anywhere (except perhaps as unobserved exceptions, which can be very bad).

Comment: like said in the articel they _"will notify **their** SynchronizationContext"_, so if there is no default SynchronizationContext in .net core they have noone to notify. Simple as that. But I would assume that their Exceptions will still be handled by `AppDomain.UnhandledException`. Also I got the felling that this is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/600226)

Comment: @Ackdari Thanks for your feedback. I expect the same but I don't know. I can assure you it's not an XY problem. I prefer knowledge over assumptions. Since I do not know and I am unable to find answers I asked a question here. This is an an effort to educate myself and also to spread knowledge in the spirit of Stackoverflow, which exists to help people to code, to learn and to share knowledge. Looking at the Microsoft documentation, threads do have a Synchronization context. So maybe this is not used in .netcore to synchronize threads, but something that can be assigned and used.

Comment: What do you mean be "report progress"? `async void` methods don't report any progress. They also don't report that they started or finished. The only thing that they report is their exception, if it occurs and it's unhandled.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That is not true, as stated in the description and the provided Microsoft documentation they do report progress in .NET Framework. 

A definition of progress is also provided in the description. 

I'm just not sure of how it works for .NET Core. If they don't report anything, that is fine. I don't know. That's why I asked. 

Side note: don't change my question & description to something else again, please.

Comment: I changed the title previously with the intention to clarify the question. I am sorry that my edit deviated from the original intent of the post. Unfortunately I must also delete my answer because it refers to the behavior of `async void` methods regarding exceptions, and not regarding "progress", whatever that means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TLDR:** No sync context, meaning context is not informed of operation started and ended. Exceptions are thrown on threadpool thread.

An `async void` method will get transformed by the compiler. Take this as an example

```
public async void Test() 
{
}
```

Resulting generated code looks something like this

```
public void Test()
{
    <Test>d__0 stateMachine = new <Test>d__0();
    stateMachine.<>4__this = this;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Create();
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncVoidMethodBuilder <>t__builder = stateMachine.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
}
```

Important part here is the `AsyncVoidMethodBuilder` `struct`. Looking at the [`Create()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,50) function, you can see that it tries to find the current `SynchronizationContext`, if there is one, then call the `virtual` `OperationStarted()`. Since there is not sync context for .net core, this will be skipped.

The next interesting part of this builder is the [`AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,154). This is the function that gets called when inside your method, you have an `await`. If an exception crops up in there, [`ThrowAsync()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,1006) happens, which will throw an exception on a threadpool thread, as there is no sync context.

Answer (score 6):

> `async void` methods notified their synchronization context when they started or finished and any exception thrown out of an async void method was directly raised to the synchronization context

Those methods never notify synchronization context. Instead, they can be scheduled to run within synchronization context if there is one.

If there is no synchronization context set when the task continuation is resuming, [`TaskScheduler` is used](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2989), and [there is always a `TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current?view=netframework-4.8).

> In ASP.NET Core, this synchronization context was removed

Yes, *this synchronization context* refers to `AspNetSynchronizationContext` in ASP.NET (not Core), which is in charge of entering the context of an HTTP request, so that data specific to a request can be used in async methods. e.g. `HttpContext.Current` is set.

How those data handled in ASP.NET Core has been changed, so there is no need to keep such problematic synchronization context any more.

Removing *this synchronization context* does not mean synchronization context is removed from .NET Core.